# Dynamo DB java syntax

Tags: java, syntax, amazon-dynamodb

What is the difference between the following dynamo db query syntax:

We used to use

```
QueryRequest queryRequest = new QueryRequest().withTableName(TABLE).withKeyConditions(keyConditions)....;
```

and in the latest documentation i see:

```
table.query("Id", replyId,
            null, ///RangeKeyCondition - not used in this example
            "PostedBy = :val", //FilterExpression
```

which one should we use? 
is it a new syntax? differences?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different flavor, same DynamoDB API. [The new Document API was introduced in Oct 2014](http://java.awsblog.com/post/Tx1DDAWQGXWITSG/Introducing-DynamoDB-Document-API-Part-1)

> .. the new Document API allows the direct use of plain old Java data
>   types and has less boilerplate.  In fact, the Dynamo Document API can
>   be used to entirely subsume what you can do with the low level client
>   (i.e. AmazonDynamoDBClient) but with a much cleaner programming model
>   and less code.

I personally still use [AmazonDynamoDBClient](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/AmazonDynamoDBClient.html) (your first code sample)

Answer (score 0):

```
        @Bean
            public AmazonDynamoDB amazonDynamoDB() {

                String accesskey = "";
                String secretkey = "";
                //
                // creating dynamo client
                BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accesskey, secretkey);
                AmazonDynamoDB dynamo = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentials);
                dynamo.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2));
                return dynamo;
            }

            @Bean
            public DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapper() {
                return new DynamoDBMapper(amazonDynamoDB());
            }

            @Bean
            public DynamoDBTemplate dynamoDBTemplate() {
                return new DynamoDBTemplate(amazonDynamoDB());
            }

    Use DynamoDbMapper for scanning the data : 
    DynamoDBQueryExpression<T> query = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<>();
query.addExpressionAttributeNamesEntry("xyz", "abc");
            List<T> results = dynamoDBMapper.query(T.class, query);
```

modify your query and will be able to search data.